# Microsoft exchange graph API Unable to delete Conversation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I am invoking Micosoft graph API's to integrate its functionality in my custom application.
When I go to invoke API to delete conversation using group id and conversation ID, I get below response . I am looking at API as mentioned in official Graph API [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-conversation?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Any idea what is wrong ? I have Group.ReadWriteAll permission for User

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidOperation",
    "message": "ConversationId isn't supported in the context of this operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d90689bb-6a3d-4e51-b538-58ecaafaa626",
      "date": "2020-05-04T11:02:27"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conjecture since I don't have enough information:

Currently, DELETE conversation is only supported for delegated access for organizational or school accounts. You cannot use DELETE conversation for application access (when there is not interactive login). You also can't use it with delegated access for personal accounts (outlook.com).

Please provide a sanitized URL and request body as that will make it easier to answer this question.