# Issues deleting group conversation using graph API

Tags: python, adal, office365api

When invoking the http delete method against the groups graph API I am getting the following error message:

```
{'error': {'code': 'ErrorInvalidOperation', 'message': "ConversationId isn't supported in the context of this operation.", 'innerError': {'date': '2020-10-06T13:29:04', 'request-id': '{REQUEST-ID}', 'client-request-id': '{CLIENT-REQUEST-ID}'}}}
```

I am using delegated permissions and a work account as application permissions and MSA's are not supported by the API and invoking a get method with the same URI returns success.

Call causing error

```
    for conversation in collection_to_delete:
        test = requests.delete(
            config["endpoint"] + "/" + config["group_id"] + "/conversations/" + conversation,
            headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},).json()
        print(test)
```

Full code can be found https://github.com/swes1110/CleanO365Conversations

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please narrow down the problematic code and error message as much as you can, and copy the relevant pieces of your code into the question, rather than linking to GitHub. The most recent commit in your repository will change, and Stack Overflow users are unlikely to do a full code review of your entire program to find the offending line. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example has other advice for doing this. Ideally, you should be showing us only the line where you make the API call and the parameters you use in that call.

Comment: Are you using a personal account or a work or school account？

Comment: Please use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide a screenshot.

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ycHGoN1.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call [Delete conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-conversation?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) MS graph api, you need to meet the following two requirements:

1. You must use a work or school account, not a personal Microsoft account.
2. You must use delegated permissions.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592134/microsoft-exchange-graph-api-unable-to-delete-conversation) is a question similar to yours for your reference.

Comment: I am using a work/school account and delegated permissions, sorry for not clarifying the work/school account in the original post.